# video.js error parsing text captions for video

Tags: javascript, video.js

I try to add text captions to video.js, but I get this error:

```
Text Track parsing errors for
```

example of test.srt content

```
1
00:01:03,982 --> 00:01:05,822
SAMANTHA: <i>Maybe for you
there's a tomorrow.</i>

2
00:01:18,246 --> 00:01:23,246
<i>Maybe for you
there's 1,000 or 3,000</i>
```

this is an example of a text.srt with text tracks, how should I handle this kind of text captions? different videos may have different formats, what is the best way to make it universal parsing?

```
      player.addRemoteTextTrack({
          kind: 'Caption 1',
          label: 1,
          language: 'en',
          id: 1,
          src: 'subtitles/test.srt',
      });
```

is there a solution or should I write a parser and how to do this?

Comment: Are you allowed to spread `<i>` tags across two lines with SRTs? Just curious.

Comment: Try removing the trailing comma at the end of `src`. It is JSON, which is non-forgiving.

Comment: Also, you need to use .vtt (not .srt) files, as mentioned in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477324

Answer (score 0):

The question is too old, but if someone comes with the same issue, this is what happened to me.

Adding **WEBVTT** to the begging of file solved the issue:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.033
Text...
```