# What is wrong with the subtitles format?(Video.js)

Tags: javascript, video.js, srt

video.js says that there is an error while parsing the .srt subtitle file, here's the content:

```
1
00:01:14,909 --> 00:01:16,999
WOMAN 1:
Well, my dad was a farmer.

2
00:01:18,162 --> 00:01:20,622
Um, like everybody else back then.

3
00:01:22,750 --> 00:01:24,920
Of course, he didn't start that way.

4
00:01:25,503 --> 00:01:27,463
[DISTANT RUMBLING]

5
00:01:30,008 --> 00:01:31,048
[ALARM BEEPING]

6
00:01:31,217 --> 00:01:33,137
MAN [OVER RADIO]:
Computer says you're too tight.

7
00:01:33,303 --> 00:01:35,853
- Nah, I got this.
- Crossing the Straights.

8
00:01:38,266 --> 00:01:40,016
- Shutting it down, Cooper.
- No!

9
00:01:41,519 --> 00:01:43,939
- Shutting it all down.
-No, I need power up!

10
00:01:46,691 --> 00:01:47,941
[COOPER YELLS]

11
00:01:48,276 --> 00:01:49,316
GIRL:
Dad?
```

as far as I know it is valid, is it? or is there a way to check how valid it is?
or why video.js says that is has some errors, couldn't find much information about this in google

Comment: I never worked with `.sub` files before. Yet I was able to find [subcheck](http://subcheck.sourceforge.net/) in less than 20 seconds. And I bet it took you a lot more to write the question. In it's current form, this question makes people consider you in ways you most likely don't like being considered.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu бля ну я не такой задрот, я хз короч писал в поисковик этой хуеты я не видел, ну ок спс, щас чекну, бля еще пёрл надо ставить, как я заебался...а, вот ради ссылочки и писал этот вопрос)))00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it is the SRT format. Video.js supports WebVTT.

Comment: Yes, VTT is needed, as the example here shows: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp There's a free SRT->VTT converter avail at: https://atelier.u-sub.net/srt2vtt/